# Unable to use acme.sh with tls-alpn-01 to renew or issue a certificate

Tags: lets-encrypt, acme, acme.sh

According to the official ACME.SH documentation [link](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh#5-use-standalone-ssl-server-to-issue-cert), issuing a certificate is as simple as running the following command:

```
$ acme.sh --issue --alpn -d example.com
```

However, I am getting the following error

```
Error, can not get domain token entry example.com for `tls-alpn-01`
The supported validation types are `http-01` `dns-01` , but you specified: `tls-alpn-01`
```

I have tried switching from the default `ZeroSSL.com` to `BuyPass.com`, but that does not help. It seems that these providers do not allow `tls-alpn-01` validation method, but it could be related to something that I am missing.

PS:
To preemptively answer some questions:

1. I have a valid domain that I replaced with "example.com"
2. The site is functional on a 443 port, but `port 80` is blocked by ISP, hence `tls-alpn-01`
3. I am stopping Nginx, and then checking with `netstat` that port 443 is not bound to a service.
4. When I run the script with `--debug 2` parameter, I get the following value for `_authorizations_map` variable

> _authorizations_map='example.com,{"identifier":{"type":"dns","value":"example.com"},"status":"pending","expires":"2021-08-18T22:53:50Z","challenges":[{"type":"http-01","url":"https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/chall/wYehJ8kQjUDiDadBJ12qKw", "status":"pending","token":"Sfga2N2KwV-2hg3wo1gYAoyFvqV87dRvG2sHw4I6ups"},{"type":"dns-01","url":"https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/chall/CkrMQdEJthf-TmWvllW-Bg", "status":"pending","token":"_AlgMGzIfSQs7673Su-njnpieba_zLpSYxiUdXDEFnz"}]}'

Comment: Tje error is saying that the method is not supported. You have to use one of the methods supported by ZeroSSL or switch provider

Answer (score 6):

Same problem, I switched from ZeroSSL to Let's encrypt CA and now it works without problems.

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/the-acme-sh-will-change-default-ca-to-zerossl-on-august-1st-2021/144052

Edit: oops, sorry.
To tell acme.sh to use Let's encrypt CA
use:

`acme.sh --set-default-ca  --server  letsencrypt`
and then try to issue again the certificate in tls-alpn-01 mode

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware ZeroSSL  didn't provide tls-alpn challenges

Comment: Thank you! Would have never guessed based on the errors.